# CSS div disabled

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Having issue with css on this page.

I am not the original owner or creator of this html page so therefore I don't know where to look in the files to fix this problem.

**Issue: I already have a auto-populate script to input the ProductID and ProductSKU fields from the URL parameter once the page loads(tested and works on other pages except for this). Now, I suspect its some jquery in the files that is causing the field input form div to be disabled until I select the calender date/time as shown in the picture below. I dont know where it could be or what built-in function it couldve came from. Any help is appreciated.**

It shows "step final disabled" but once I select the calender date and time, it will turn into "step final". I think this is the issue on why my auto-form populate is not working but im not 100% sure.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, this is just a `disabled` class. It doesn't actually disable input (it's on a div anyway). Secondly, this is coming from your [Easy Appointments](https://wordpress.org/plugins/easy-appointments/) plugin at one of these line numbers:

```
js/frontend-bootstrap.js:377:                jQuery(element).addClass('disabled');
js/frontend-bootstrap.js:400:            calendarEl.parent().next().addClass('disabled');
js/frontend-bootstrap.js:614:                plugin.$element.find('.step').addClass('disabled');
js/frontend-bootstrap.js:807:            this.$element.find('.final').addClass('disabled');
```

Check file:
`wp-content/plugins/easy-appointments/js/frontend-bootstrap.js`

Comment: Hmm, i removed all those and the "disabled " isnt there anymore, but its still not auto-populating...It works on the [ea_standard] version but just not on [ea_bootstrap]. weird.